# ERROR exception=AttributeError("'Member' object has no attribute 'voice'")>

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to create a small Discord bot that plays radio stations. It's for a small Discord server I have with my friends.

However, when I send commands to it, it doesn't respond and I get the following error in the console:

*Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-13' coro=<join() done, defined at main.py:25> exception=AttributeError("'Member' object has no attribute 'voice'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 30, in join
voice_state = ctx.author.voice
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'voice'*

No matter how hard I look for it I can't find the error, could someone please help me?

I have tried writing the command codes in several ways, I even searched the Intents library to see if the member class exists.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version of [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)?

Comment: Yes, I'm  using discord.py 2.2.2

Comment: Can we please see your code?

Comment: Yes, of course.
I can't share it because it exceeds the character limit, but I have it hosted on replit:

https://replit.com/@gambrinus/GambriRadioDiscord#main.py

Comment: Kindly don't (ab)use replit to host a Discord bot. It's not made to run bots on, and so it causes more issues than you can imagine, and you can't fix any of them. We get posts in the d.py server multiple times a day about people who have issues they can't do anything about - other than getting a real vps.

Answer (score 1):

That `Interactions` package is not `discord.py`.

Everything related to interactions or slash commands is built-in to the discord.py library. You should uninstall `Interactions`, force-reinstall `discord.py`, use **only** `discord.py` instead, and fix your code up.

Refer to the official examples for more info: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/app_commands